# How azure function HttpTrigger edit code parameter name?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

Azure Function HttpTrigger default use `code` parameter with token code, e.g: `https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/xxxHttpTriggerCSharp?code=)#&)@^$^@#)`

How can I replace `code` name by `token` like:
`https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/xxxHttpTriggerCSharp?token=)#&)@^$^@#)`

[image]

The situation I met:
A service also uses the code parameter, which leads to conflicts in authentication.

Comment: I think it is no possible. If you have an authentication type like 'function', then you need to give the function key. 'code=' is by design, I think your requirement is impossible.

Comment: What about creating a Proxy in azure functions and setup the actual Http Endpoint; the proxy change the token query parameter to code as needed by azure functions (or can be done by Http Request header too). Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is no possible. If you have an authentication type like 'function', then you need to give the function key. 'code=' is by design, I think your requirement is impossible.

If you don't want to use the authentication type, you can set the authentication type to anonymous(If you use script language, you can set it in the functin.json. If you use language that needs to be compiled, you can set it in the declaration part).

Comment: Making the function anonymous means giving up security. I don't see this as good advice. The other answer should be the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

You could send the `code` value as a header instead: `x-functions-key`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#api-key-authorization

This would free up the `code` parameter for use.